# How to read a excel column with multiple currency symbols in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

[Sample values in the column ₡
$
L
C$
Q](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U0Jct.jpg)

when i try to access this column in pandas dataframe it throws the error as follows

UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u20a1' in position 25: character maps to

Answer (score 0):

If your excel sheet is formatted as

currency, some number

$,45

%,76

You could just download it as a CSV then do

```
df = pd.read_csv("filename.txt")
```

Then,

```
currency_symbols = df.drop("currency",axis = 1)
```

Then, your DF will be the dataframe without the currency symbols, and you will have an array with all of the currency symbols in currency_symbols

If, instead, you have a file that looks like

$45

%109
...

Where the currency is followed by the number you want to extract, you could do the following:

```
currency_symbols = ["$","%"]
df = pd.read_csv("yourfile.csv")
currencies = []
values = []
for elem in df["currency"].values:
    string = elem 
    for e in currency_symbols:
        if e in elem:
            currencies.append(e)
            string = string.replace(e,"")
    values.append(string)
```

Then, you would get two arrays:

currencies = ["$","%"]

and

values = ["45","109"]

Comment: I just have the currency symbols in the column and i have to do some calculation with those currencies is there a way to read those currency symbols without getting unicode encode error